# Show only rows that contain data in one specific column

Tags: php

I have a table that contains thousands of rows. I'm trying to show only rows that have information in a specific column.  The column name is "vhf" the table name is "p_loc". The majority of the rows contain no info in the column "vhf" but, when I try the code below it wants to echo all my rows.

I just need the rows that contain any information in the column "vhf"

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT vhf FROM p_loc WHERE vhf IS NOT NULL");
```

Comment: Are the values actually NULL or are they just blank spaces? There is a big difference.

Comment: What is the default set to in your tables structure in php admin

Comment: They are just blank spaces

Comment: Well then they are not NULL. Look at the answer in the link on @FuzzyTree's comment

Comment: No, Null has a completely different meaning than a blank space. Null means there is no value assigned, nothing. A blank space is a string with no length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like there are two cases you want to filter out:

1. the vhf column is NULL
2. the vhf column is empty, or an empty string

This means you need two clauses in your SELECT:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT vhf FROM p_loc WHERE vhf IS NOT NULL AND vhf != ''");
```